# 02 mazda protege5..will only start in nuetral

Tags: mazda-5

I have a mazda protege 5 that will only start in nuetral and i need to know if it is possible and safe to drive after starting my vehicle this way?

Comment: So after its been started in either D or N, i can then drive where-ever as if i had started it in P?

Comment: Have the neutral safety switch replaced.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an automatic then it should only start in P or N.

If it is manual then it may only start in neutral and, on some cars, when the clutch is pushed down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can drive the car without further damage. I would start the engine, however, only when the gearshift is in N.

An automatic transmission car should only start in P or N. To return the transmission to correct functioning, the transmission's neutral safety switch should be adjusted or replaced.